# i get this error while getting Jsone data in andriod Volley. I don't know where is error

Tags: android

> Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value 
>   {"Description":"sd","Title_Image":"pic5.png","Vedio_Title":"sometitle","S_category_Id":"1","}
>   of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

My Android code is

```
public class ShowData extends AppCompatActivity {
private  String url="http://192.168.2.10/Library/A/ShowAllData.php";
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private List<item> list=new ArrayList<item>();
    private ListView listView;
    private itemAdapter adapter;    
public class ShowData extends AppCompatActivity {
private  String url="http://192.168.2.10/Library/A/ShowAllData.php";
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private List<item> list=new ArrayList<item>();
    private ListView listView;
    private itemAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.showdata);
listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        adapter=new itemAdapter(this,list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        dialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading.....");
        Log.d("I Am near ","to jsonarray");


        JsonArrayRequest  jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
          // hide();


                ////////get json data
                for(int i=0; i<response.length(); i++){

                    try {
                        JSONObject obj=response.getJSONObject(i);
                       item item=new item();
                       item.setTitlwimage(obj.getString("Title_Image"));
                        item.setTitle(obj.getString("Ved_Title"));
                        item.setDescription(obj.getString("Description"));
                        item.setCate(obj.getInt("S_category_Id"));
                        //item.setTime(obj.getString());
                        Log.d("I Am near ","to loop");
                    list.add(item);
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("Error"," and "+String.valueOf(response));
                }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        Singleton.getinstance().addrequest(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
    public void hide(){
        if(dialog!=null){

            dialog.dismiss();
            dialog=null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`{"Description":"sd","Title_Image":"pic5.png","Vedio_Title":"sometitle","S_category_Id":"1","}` is itself a `JSONObject` which is passed in `response` I assume. You cannot call `getJSONObject` on a `JSONObject` itself.

Try to put `{"Description":"sd","Title_Image":"pic5.png","Vedio_Title":"sometitle","S_category_Id":"1","}` within a JSON array (which will look like `[{"Description":"sd","Title_Image":"pic5.png","Vedio_Title":"sometitle","S_category_Id":"1","}]`) from wherever you are giving out the response.

Comment: Thank you to solve my problem .I did the mistake in php file

Comment: Glad to help. If the problem is solved, click on that tick button.